# Is there a way to have the name of the webpage as the default file name when using Print to File in Firefox?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, firefox, printing

I frequently save webpages as PDF files to read later on Sony Digital Paper. However, when printing the webpage in Firefox, the default behavior is different on Windows, MacOS and Ubuntu. Only on MacOS is the name of the webpage used as the default file name. On Windows the file name is empty while on Ubuntu it's always "mozilla.pdf" for some reason.

Is there a way to immediately have the name of the webpage as the default file name? I now have to type the file name manually every time which is a tremendous waste of time. On Ubuntu there was [a suggestion](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1933296) to use `cups-pdf` as the PDF printer. Is there also a solution for Windows?